# Ajax.Request of prototype framework hangs with multiple calls to jsp page

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, google-chrome, prototypejs

I have a problem concerning multiple ajax requests using prototype.js version 1.7.

Here is the function I wrote to make the ajax call:

```
function checkClonability(element) {

var strUrl = "/dssweb/js/ajaxdbdispatcher";

var rowIndex = element.id.split('_')[1];
var tabschema = $('tabschema_' + rowIndex).innerHTML.trim();
var tabname = $('tabname_' + rowIndex).innerHTML.trim();
var op = <%=AjaxDbDispatcher.CLONE_TABLE_COMPARE%>;

workLevel(rowIndex, 'run');

var qb = new QueryStringBuilder();
qb.addParameter('op', op);
qb.addParameter('dbsource', 'UAT');
qb.addParameter('dbtarget', 'PROD');
qb.addParameter('tabschema', tabschema);
qb.addParameter('tabname', tabname);

new Ajax.Request(strUrl, {
    method:'post',
    asynchronous: true,
    parameters: qb.toString(),
    onSuccess: function(transport){
        var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();

        if(json.equals) {
            workLevel(rowIndex, 'ok');
            element.onclick = '';
        } else {
            element.checked = false;
            element.disabled = true;
            workLevel(rowIndex, 'ko', 'La tabella ha un tracciato diverso in produzione!');
        }
    },
    onFailure: function(err){ 
        workLevel(rowIndex, 'none', 'Si è verificato un errore durante la verifica.');
    }
});
```

}

The strUrl is a java servlet that makes a comparison of a database table between two different environments.
My page shows a list of tables and checkboxes to select them.
The function is fired by an onclick event on a checkbox. Everything works fine for a single call, but it hangs if I try to check several checkboxes without waiting for the end of the first call.
I tried it on chrome 8 and IE6 and I'm working on apache tomcat 6.

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: can you show a table markup sample and how you hook to the click event ?

Comment: I chatch the click directly in the checkbox: <input type="checkbox" onclick="myfunction..();" .. />. I have a 'multi-click' situation i.e. if I hit the 'select all' button (it loops throw all checkboxes and run the myCheckboxInstance.click(); method for each one.

Answer (score 0):

when a user click two times quickly, the ajax request is send twice. Put some variable and a test on it that will stop a second execution if the ajax call hasnt ended:

```
var running = true;
function clickHandler() {
    if (running) return;
    running = true;

    /** Some stuff here ***/

    new Ajax.Request(strUrl, {
        method:'post',
        asynchronous: true,
        parameters: qb.toString(),
        onSuccess: function(transport){
            var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();

            if(json.equals) {
                workLevel(rowIndex, 'ok');
                element.onclick = '';
            } else {
                element.checked = false;
                element.disabled = true;
                workLevel(rowIndex, 'ko', 'La tabella ha un tracciato diverso in produzione!');
            }
        },
        onFailure: function(err){ 
            workLevel(rowIndex, 'none', 'Si è verificato un errore durante la verifica.');
        },
        onComplete: function() { running = false; }
    });

}
```

NB: note sure about the onComplete callback, check the manuals to be sure running will be set false whenever the ajax call ends.

Comment: (the edit took me too much) I already thounght to the solution you suggest, but I'd like that all calls will be satisfied. i.e. if the user select three different tables (by checking its checkbox) I'd like that all the requests are correctly executed. I'd like to be able to make simultaneous ajax calls together, but it seems that Ajax.Request doesn't make it possible (or more probably I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I've solved my problem with this 'workaround' class. 
It syncronizes calls and make them sequential:

```
var Syncro = Class.create(
    {
        initialize: function(params) {
            // Check for Prototype class
            if(typeof Prototype=='undefined') {
                throw("JSSyncro requires the Prototype JavaScript framework to run.");
            }

            //handle input parameters
            this.delay = (typeof params.delay == 'undefined' ? 1000 : params.delay);

            this.allowDuplicates = (
                    typeof params.allowDuplicates=='undefined' || typeof params.allowDuplicates!='boolean'
                        ? true : params.allowDuplicates);

            this.order = (
                    typeof params.order=='undefined' || ['fifo','lifo'].indexOf(params.order)==-1 
                        ? 'fifo' : params.order);

            this.operations = [];
            this.terminated = true;

            // private - check for duplicate operations in the stack
            this.alreadyExists = function(operation) {
                var exists = false;

                this.operations.each(
                        function(element) {
                            if(element.toString()==operation.toString()) {
                                exists = true;
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                );

                return exists;
            };

            //private - run operations sequentially
            this.runSyncronized = function() {
                function nextTimeout(instance) {
                    setTimeout(
                            function(){
                                instance.runSyncronized();
                            }, 
                            this.delay);
                }

                if(this.operations.length>0) {
                    if(this.terminated) {
                        this.terminated = false;

                        var cmd = (this.order=='fifo' 
                            ? this.operations.shift() : this.operations.pop());

                        cmd();
                    } else {
                        nextTimeout(this);
                    }
                } else {
                    this.terminated = true;
                }
            };
        },

        // public - wakeup the executor and run the following operation if the previous is terminated 
        setTerminated: function(boolValue) {
            this.terminated = boolValue;
        },
        // public - set the operation to execute sequentially
        execute: function(operation) {
            if(this.allowDuplicates || !this.alreadyExists(operation)) {
                this.operations.push(operation);

                this.runSyncronized();
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Syncro class has two main methods:

execute - where you can pass the function you must execute inside an anonymous function
setTerminated - a setter method useful to set that an asyncronous operation has terminated (i.e. set in the onComplete method the async call done with ajax).

checkboxClick function is obviously called in the onclick event of my checkboxes.

Hope this could be useful.

Bye.

Just an evolution in the constructor.
Initial parameters (passed in the constructor) are defined in an array:
new Syncro({[delay:1000][, allowDuplicates:true|false][, order:'lifo'|'fifo']});